# Ajax not returning echo when form is a success

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a from that submits data when a buttons pressed.  If the form is success, the form returns nothing.  When the form errors out, it does send an error.  Essentially, I want it to forward to a page after the data has inserted into the database.

I have ran this in a debug with netbeans and it returns the echo from the php on success.  It does not when just using a browser.  I have tried saying

```
[code] if (response === 'Saved') {
do this}else{do that}[code]
```

but no joy

```
<input type = "submit" name = "register" id = "reg_btn" >
```

```
 $('#reg_btn').on('click', function(){
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    if (email_state === false || fname_state === false || lname_state === false || pword_state === false) {
      $('#error_msg').text('Fix the errors in the form first');
      return false;
    }else if (email_state === true && fname_state === true && lname_state === true && pword_state && true)
    {
      // proceed with form submission
      $.ajax({
        url: '../PHP/reg2.php',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'save' : 1,
            'email' : email,
            'fname' : fname,
            'password' : password,
        'lname' : lname

        },
        success: function(response){


                alert(response);
            window.location = 'succesful_registration.html';
                    }

        }
      });
    }
 });
```

```php
   $db = mysqli_connect ("localhost","snapitlive","2XEq6NI0QortZIdh","snapitlive");
  if($db == false)
    {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $webform = (filter_Input(\INPUT_POST, 'save', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    if ($webform) {
    $first_name = filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'fname', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $last_name = filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'lname',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $email = filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $mobile = filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'mobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $uniqid = \uniqid();
    $password = filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'password',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $hashpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $pw_uniqid = \uniqid();
/*$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_ea='$email'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
      echo "exists";    
      exit();
    }else{*/
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (u_id, u_fn, u_ln, u_ea, u_mp) VALUES ('$uniqid','$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$mobile');";
            $sql .="INSERT INTO passwords(p_id, p_u_id, password, current) VALUES ('$pw_uniqid', '$uniqid', '$hashpass', 1);";

            $results = \mysqli_multi_query($db, $sql);
            echo 'Saved';


    exit();
    mysql_close($db);
    }
```

I expect an alert message saying saved, then to direct to the location i mention.  Instead I just get the page refreshed.

Comment: is the `alert(response);` executed? What it shows?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's developer tools to inspect the request and raw response?

Comment: does the ajax request succeed? You can check this really easy for example with chrome dev tools, network tab.

Comment: You are at risk of SQL Injection, please switch to prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: It only appears to execute when theres an error.  , I am unsure how to check the raw response.  When I look in Chrome, it just shows me the code, but doesnt step in. The ajax executes as it goes to my database with the data in.

Comment: `mysql_close($db);` is a syntax error. Remove that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have brackets mistake end of the script that's the correct way and windows location must either two 
`window.location.assign("url") 
 OR  window.location.replace("url")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reg_btn').on('click', function(){
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    if (email_state === false || fname_state === false || lname_state === false || pword_state === false) {
      $('#error_msg').text('Fix the errors in the form first');
      return false;
    }else if (email_state === true && fname_state === true && lname_state === true && pword_state && true)
    {
      // proceed with form submission
      $.ajax({
            url: '../PHP/reg2.php',
            type: "post",
            data: {
                'save' : 1,
                'email' : email,
                'fname' : fname,
                'password' : password,
            'lname' : lname

            },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
                window.location.replace("succesful_registration.html");
            }
        });
      }
});
```

Comment: And use developer console with console.log() for next time also change your editor phpstorm sublime atom any of that can show the right way use xdebugger for PHP error handling that will give you a lot of time believe me I been there for too long

Comment: Thanks @samuhay.  I will try a different editor to use with my project.  As for the changes, I have amended to match what you have said.  But it still does not relocate the page.    If make ajax look at a dummy page instead of the correct page (i.e a page that doesnt exists), it will relocate to the registration page.

Comment: Try to console.log("what you want to console") right click any go developer tool CTRL+f5 for sure and give me result and you can try some of them from here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp iT2 propabily window.location.href you looking for redirection to page

Comment: it's probably "window.location.href" you looking for redirection to page

Comment: Thanks @Samuhay.  I tried everything.  In the end, I reinstalled xampp and it worked.  There was some issue with my server it seems.  I appreciate all your help

Comment: No problem anytime you can ask php laravel mysql realet questons